# Superfish sub-menu horizontal

Tags: navigation

Have a Superfish menu on a purchased Drupal 7 theme. sub-links off the main menu currently drop down vertically. I cannot figure out how to enable/configure the Superfish MegaMenu so the sub-links can be displayed horizontally as follows:

ITEM1 
 - subitem     - subitem     - subitem
 - subitem     - subitem     - subitem
 - subitem     - subitem     - subitem
 - subitem     - subitem     - subitem